# Display data from database by spcific id

Tags: php, mysql

I create the simple cart app. In these i want to add the product to the cart, from that cart i choose only one product to be buy. I getting confuse in using id. can anyone help me to solve this problem?

here is the code for adding to the cart:

```
<?php     
Include('connect.php');

$productId=$_POST['productId'];
$productName=$_POST['productName'];
$productPrice=$_POST['productPrice'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO products    (productId,productName,productPrice,quantity) 
VALUES ('$productId','$productName','$productPrice','$quantity')") or     die(mysql_error());

if($sql){ 

$_GET['productId']=$productId;
header('Location:buy.php');
} 
else
{
echo"Failed to add cart !";

}
?>
```

Here is the code for fetching product and display:

```
 <?php 
 include('connect.php');




 $sql="SELECT productName FROM products WHERE productId=" . $productId . "";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 $myArray = array(); 

 echo "<table  style='width:50%;'>
 <tr>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Product Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>

</tr>";

 $index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
 $myArray[$index] = $row;
 $index++;

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['productName'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['productPrice'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: From where "$productId" will have value in second code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysql_insert_id()

Example:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You select only one column from the product table. but you try to show `$row['productPrice']` and `$row['quantity']` where you don't fetch this data.

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId='. $productId .'";
```

Or

```
$sql="SELECT productName, productPrice, quantity FROM products WHERE productId='. $productId .'";
```

Comment: I try that But i have receiving error that undefined index

Comment: check the `$result` did you get any data from the query using this code : `print_r($result); exit;`

Comment: i dnt know, But I using the code ,i have receiving the undefined index error and Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource